# Tips for writing an admin interface in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, metaprogramming

I've been following [this tutorial](http://iain.nl/backends-in-rails-3-1) on creating a backend administration section for a rails 3 app.

I like the way it works, but the developer is required to manually generate namespaced controllers and models for each resource they want to administer in the backend.

RailsAdmin, in contrast, does not require you to do this, instead it detects which models you have in your app, and sets up admin sections for each one, without you having to generate any extra code.

Are there any resources out there, where I can learn to make my admin section work a little bit more like RailsAdmin? (I tried reading the RailsAdmin codebase but I get lost as there's  quite a lot going on).

Ideally, I'd like my admin section to detect my application's models, and magically create admin pages for each one depending on that model's attributes. I'm certainly not asking anyone to write my code here, just looking for some tips on where to go in order to find out more about this sort of metaprogramming.

Comment: why don't you see how it's implemented in RailsAdmin?

Comment: I can't actully figure out how RailsAdmin do it. Do you know? Their codebase is quite complex. I'm surprised there's less information on this sort of thing to be honest.